# Firebase Analytics - how to see statistics for select_content event grouped by item_id

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have implemented Firebase analytics on my iOS and Android app and I would like to see statistics for the select_content event grouped by the item_id parameter. I can apply filter in the "Events in the last 30 minutes" section to see the statistics based on event_id as such:
[image: Firebase - filtered by item_id parameter]

But the "Content" section shows only the content_type:
[image]

If I click on the content_type, I see (not set) even though the item_id parameter was obviously captured:
[image]

Is there some problem in my integration or is there no way to see the statistics based on item_id?

Thanks!